# ElementNotInteractableException exception while finding a element using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a menu on my web page which uses the below code and I am trying to Automate using selenium web driver and java.

This is my HTML code:

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0); class="bars">
     ::before
     ::after
```

I Am trying to find the element using

```
WebElement bars=driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
bars.click();
```

but I am getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable exception . ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are misunderstanding the locator, and add `WebDriverWait`, please try this :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='bars']")));
WebElement bars=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='bars']"));
bars.click();
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. When I press the menu button it focuses on the ::before CSS attribute and when I close the menu it focuses on the ::after while inspecting the element.